# How to make scrollbars darker under Awesomewm?

Tags: awesome

I'm using archlinux with awesomewm and kterminal (the kde terminal app).

Whenever I'm using the terminal (or any other app, but specifically the terminal), and whenever I wanted to scroll, I find it very difficult to see the scroll bar so I can hold it with the mouse. Its color is so light that it is almost identical to the background.

Is there a way to make it black or even a little bit darker so I can see it better?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Solution: Use gnome-terminal instead. This is the only solution.

Comment: Hmmm… of course you know that awesomewm is based on xcb. As well you know that kterminal is based on libgdx. OK! Let's admit that gnome-terminal is a **possible** solution but… do you really believe that whatever gtk based terminal is something OP is ready for and… even more… the **only** solution ?

Comment: Sorry what is OP?

Comment: Hmm… In this precise case… it seems that I should feel sorry. as I should have realized that you were the author of the question. I use this acronym referring to the Opening Poster because, when reviewing QAs, user-names are informations I just don't care about. (no disrespect meant. It's just that they influence neither my votes nor my comments). My bad then. I however stand on my here-above comment, changing only the wording : s/OP is ready for/you want/